# Tekken TT2 - Using weapon items from costumes?

Tags: tekken-tag-tournament-2

In Tekken Tag Tournament 2, how do you use items of weaponry such as guns and grenades from the costumes? I can't really see the buttons there since it's so small. The items I'm talking about are the two items that the characters can carry on their Upper Body and Lower Body. It's not the clothing, it's the items.
You find these in the CUSTOMIZE section of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for SOME of the items:

http://tekken.wikia.com/wiki/Tekken_Tag_Tournament_2/Item_Moves

u/d/l/r = up/down/left/right respectively

1/2/3/4 = left punch/right punch/left kick/right kick respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Each item move have their own unique commands. As you noted the commands can be seen when purchasing or equipping the item in the customize menu.

You can also find the list of item moves [here](http://tekken.wikia.com/wiki/Tekken_Tag_Tournament_2/Item_Moves)

Comment: I saw the link... I don't get the commands. Could you please explain them to me? I assume the letters stand for Up, Down, Left, Right, but I have no idea what the numbers mean.

Comment: The numbers are based on a popular Tekken notation which you can read up on http://www.tekkenzaibatsu.com/legend.php

Comment: Are you sure that website shows ALL of the items?